# How to count the number of string words in a column of lists?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe like:

```
Artist        Genre

  A          ['Pop','Rock']
  B          ['Pop']
  C          ['Rock', 'Electro']
```

I want to find the frequency of each genre in the dataframe , ie:

```
Genre         Count

'Pop'           2
'Rock'          2 
'Electro'       1
```

I have tried this:

```
s = pd.Series(Counter([y for x in raw_data_genre['Genre'] for y in x]))

s
```

But I end up with something weird like

```
[     6
'    10
p     4
o     5
p     4
```

Any help?
I know this is because of the quotes on the elements, this is a pre given dataset so I need to remove them? I've tried to use other similar question solutions but they don't seem to work hence why i'm asking this.

Comment: What is the `dtype` of the column? It seems like you might have stored strings that actually have the brackets and quotes in them, rather than lists. Please show how you create the Dataframe in the first place. If it's unsuitable for your purposes, then the problem should be fixed at the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, Convert string to list using `literal_eval` + [`Series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) Transform each element of a list-like to a row, followed by [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get count's

```
from ast import literal_eval

print(df.Genre.apply(literal_eval).explode().value_counts())
```

---

```
Pop        2
Rock       2
Electro    1
```

Comment: It gave me an error: malformed node or string: ["'pop'"]

Comment: try without literal_eval, ``df.Genre.explode().value_counts()`` it looks like you column value is already a list object.

Comment: yes amazing thank you!!!